# Последовательность содержит более одного соответствующего элемента

Tags: c#, mvc, entity-framework

При получении данных возникает ошибка "Последовательность содержит более одного соответствующего элемента".
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?

```
public class BaseClass
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Analit")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class Reference: BaseClass
{
    [Column("Kod")]
    public string Kod { get; set; }
    public virtual string NameAn { get; set; }
}

public class Organisation: Reference
{
    [Column("NameAn")]
    public override string NameAn { get; set; }
}

public class Target: Reference
{
    public int? OrganisationID { get; set; }
    public virtual Organisation Organisation { get; set; } //**без этого свойства ошибки не возникает**
    public override string NameAn  { get; set; }

    [Column("Section1")]
    public string State { get; set; }
}

public class PLM_Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Target> Target { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BaseClass> BaseClass { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Organisation> Organisation { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Target>().Map(m => m.Requires("Vid").HasValue(3605));
        modelBuilder.Entity<Organisation>().Map(m => m.Requires("Vid").HasValue(3776));
    }
}



public class MyController : Controller
{
   PLM_Context context = new PLM_Context();
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      var org = context.Organisation.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ID == OrganisationID); //При построении приложения в этом месте исключение
   }
}
```

Comment: а уверены, что используется `FirstOrDefault` а не `SingleOrDefault`?

Comment: Добрый день. Да, используется `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: Ошибки не возникает, если сделать так:
`public class KPI_Target: Reference
    {
        [Column("Section1")]
        public string State { get; set; }`
Сдается, что ошибка в наследовании

Comment: у меня нечто подобное было, когда в таблице в бд было несколько записей с одинаковым внешним ключем, хотя связь была 1 к 1. может быть дело в этом. Я тогда удалил одну запись и все пофиксилось. Попробуй проверить это.

Answer (score 2):

Странное у вас наследование. Вообще-то, в контексте не должно быть наборов (DbSet) для ребенка и родителя одновременно!

Я так понимаю, ваш BaseClass - это просто контейнер для ID, в базе отдельная таблица ему не нужна. Поэтому вам в контексте надо завести ровно 1 набор сущностей:

```
public DbSet<References> References { get; set; }
```

В таком случае, к организациям можно будет обратиться через OfType:

```
context.References.OfType<Organisation>().FirstOrDefault(o => o.ID == OrganisationID);
```

Или же можно найти по ID любой Reference, а потом уже привести его к Organisation (но тогда запрос будет медленнее, потому что EF будет проверять все варианты возможных наследников):

```
(Organisation)context.References.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ID == OrganisationID);
```